# Moving old laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, thunderbird, email

Want to install Lubuntu 14.04 on my mom's Celeron laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, which is too slow.

Main thing she uses is Thunderbird for email. I will install Thunderbird on Lubuntu again as her mail client instead of Sylpheed. I want to move her current Thunderbird installation, messages etc. to storage device, then install Lubuntu with Thunderbird and then import her current Thunderbird. How do I do this?

Comment: Edit your question and remove unnecessary data, get to the directly

Comment: Sorry, but not sure that works for me. Not concerned about moving across distributions. Want to move permanently to Lubuntu - what is the best way to get to a clean Lubuntu install and I only want to move her emails from Thunderbird.

Comment: i have update the answer with a possible method

Answer (score 0):

if emails are the only concern then do fresh install, which will be better.

**How to migrate emails from Thunderbird emails to Sylpheed ?**

- first export the mails from Thunderbird ([link on how to export](http://its.isber.ucsb.edu/guides/exporting-e-mail-thunderbird)). Make sure you follow cautions in order to export all subdirectories. **Export mail in EML format**, from which Sylpheed can easily import. Done !

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu itself is just Ubuntu optimized to work with `lxde` environment. What you can do is install `lxde` itself and avoid unnecessary migration of data.  That can be achieved with `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and reboot. On next boot simply select new environment. For good measure you can set it as default for your user account within `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/username`. Here's mine for instance, notice `XSession` line:

```
[com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService]
PlayerName=''
Timestamp=0
Title=''
Artist=''
Album=''
ArtUrl=''
PlayerIcon=<('themed', <['application-default-icon', 'application-default', 'application']>)>

[User]
Language=en_US
FormatsLocale=en_US.UTF-8
XSession=ubuntu
Background=/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy.xml
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/penguin.jpg
SystemAccount=false

[InputSource0]
xkb=us

[InputSource1]
xkb=ru

[InputSource2]
ibus=sunpinyin

[InputSource3]
ibus=libpinyin

[InputSource4]
xkb=cn
```

Comment: How do I add her Thunderbird which is on Ubuntu to Lubuntu? If I search for Thunderbird on Lubuntu, will it show her current Tbird or prompt me to download a new install of Tbird for Lubuntu?

Comment: @Geerit Thunderbird isnt' made for Lubuntu or Ubuntu exclusively.  It works across versions. If you simply install `lubuntu-desktop` , the programs will work. Just like I have `ubuntu` and `xubuntu-desktop`, but one and the same `firefox` works in both

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)